# Python Filter Specific Post Response

Tags: python, json, http-post, httprequest

My Python code sends JSON POST request to a service and it gets back a JSON with information.

My Code:

```
for username in data:
    for text in data[username]:
        body = json.dumps({ "text": text['text'], "extract_type": "mitie"})
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
        print "---New Request---"
        print (r.content)
```

Response I get:

```
---New Request---
[{"score":0.6997741063788492,"tag":"LOCATION","label":"USA"},
{"score":1.0501661504998254,"tag":"MISC","label":"European"}]
---New Request---
[{"score":0.12021601772708868,"tag":"ORGANIZATION","label":"NFL"}]
---New Request---
[{"score":0.16843877285343356,"tag":"MISC","label":"Watermel"},
{"score":0.46122731000101685,"tag":"MISC","label":"Professional"},
{"score":0.6470543353899144,"tag":"LOCATION","label":"USA"}]
```

I am trying to check if it has the `"tag":"LOCATION"` and then extract the `label` into a variable.

I've tried adding

```
for username in data:
    for text in data[username]:
        #print text['text']
        body = json.dumps({ "text": text['text'], "extract_type": "mitie"})
        r = requests.post('http://54.174.131.124:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
        print "---New Request---"
        print (r.content)

        if "LOCATION" in r.content['tag']:
            location = r.content['label']
```

but I get the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Given that you know it's JSON, have you tried [`r.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe where would I add that? The issue I think lies in my if statement but I am not sure how to do it. `r.content` is what is being show in my response so that part works.

Comment: `if r.json().get('tag') == 'LOCATION': ...`? Read up on dictionaries.

Comment: `r.content` is a list of one or more items.  You need to grab each item from the list and then extract `'tag'` and `'label'` from it.

Answer (score 0):

In requests, the repsonse `content` is the raw response, which is a string. You are trying to use it as a dict, which is why `r.content['tag']` raises a TypeError.

In order to use the response json data, you need to decode the json response using [r.json()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content). It will return a list of dicts(the json data in the question,decoded) which you can filter by 'tag' and then extract the label.

Comment: I replaced the if statement in my code with 

`decoded = r.json()`
`if decoded.get("tag") == 'LOCATION':`
     `print "test"`

and I received a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'.` 


I now understand the difference between the r.content and r.json() but I am not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: @Joey ah, sorry; your JSON is a *list* of dictionaries.

Comment: Its because your data is a list of json objects, which is decoded to a list of dicts in python. So in your code, `decoded` is a list(of dict), but not a dict, that's why `decoded.get("tag")` fails. But `decoded[0].get("tag")`, `decoded[1].get("tag")` etc will work as expected.